# Get a line number from exception in JScript

Tags: windows, jscript, wsh, windows-scripting

I'm running the following code in Windows Script Host (not web browser.) Is there a way to get the line number where exception occurred?

```
try
{
    //Exception happens here
}
catch (e) 
{
    //Get line number from 'e'?
}
```

PS. Note that if I don't catch this exception a default Windows error has the line number.

Comment: It looks to me like what you are asking is not possible from WSH scripts.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Yeah, it seems the same to me :( Thanks for confirming. Although this is weird because the WSH engine itself has this info that it can display in its own error report.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Insert the [job processing instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hfwskb1.aspx)

  ```
  <?job error="flag" debug="flag" ?>
  ```

> Arguments
>
> error
>
> A Boolean value. False is the default value for all attributes. Set to true to allow error messages for syntax or run-time errors in the Windows Script (.wsf) file.
>
> debug
>
> A Boolean value. False is the default value for all attributes. Set to true to enable debugging. If debugging is not enabled, you will be unable to launch the script debugger for a Windows Script file.

```
<package>
   <job id="DoneInVBS">
      <?job debug="true"?>
      <script language="VBScript">
         WScript.Echo "This is VBScript"
      </script>
   </job>

   <job id="DoneInJS">
      <?job debug="true"?>
      <script language="JScript">
         WScript.Echo("This is JScript"); 
      </script>
   </job>
</package>
```

- Install the [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=22185)
- Add the [debug flags and registry settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308364/)

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script\Settings\JITDebug

  wscript.exe //d <path to WSH file>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

JScript Error object doesn't have any line or column information, only `description`, `message`, `name`, `stack`, `stackTraceLimit` and `number`. Reference is here: [Error Object (JavaScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dww52sbt%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)